# React: Having a button select something upon click a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently have 4 buttons and 4 circles with 4 numbers each. When someone clicks button 1, circle 1 would be selected. When they click button 2, circle 2 would be selected. I currently have this:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      selButtonIdx: 1,
    };
  }

  handleButtonSelection = (selButtonIdx) => {
    this.setState({ selButtonIdx: selButtonIdx });
    console.log(selButtonIdx);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">Buttons</header>
        <main>
          <CircleSelector
            selButtonIdx={this.state.selButtonIdx}
            handleButtonSelection={this.handleButtonSelection}
          />
          <Circles />
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

For my CircleSelector I have:

```
const CircleSelector = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="CircleSelector">
      {[1, 2, 3, 4].map((index) => (
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={() => props.handleButtonSelection(index)}
        >
          Select Button {index} {index === props.selButtonIdx && "(selected)"}
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

and for circles:

```
const Circle = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="Circles">
      {[1, 2, 3, 4].map((index) => (
        <div type="text">{index}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yoou should integrate your circle and your button in the same component, this way you can simply use a reference to select the circle. I did the following example with input since i don't know what your circle contains but the idea is here :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {[1, 2, 3, 4].map(el => (
        <MyComponent />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const MyComponent = () => {
  const elRef = React.createRef();

  const selectElement = () => {
    elRef.current.select(); // Select the content of the input
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={selectElement}>Select element</button>
      <input ref={elRef} type="text" value="element" />
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Here is the [repro on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yjg2wc?file=index.js)